# Adding static files to PHP application

Tags: php

I'm looking at this as a starting point for my application:
https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal

My question is, where do I put my CSS, JS etc.

Is the proper approach to this to do this:

**Root Folder**

```
Application
    _installation
    classes
    config
    libraries
    views
    index.php
    register.php
public_html
    css
    js
    img
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your `Application` is publically accessible? If not, than your website will not work. Usually only `public_html` is accessible as root of website, so there must be `index.php`.

If `Application` is your web root, `public_html` is also accessible from web and all paths are set up to use css from `public_html`, than it's ok.

---

*How usually it works*

You put everything under `public_html`

```
public_html
  /*
   * When going to www.example.com, you will be located
   * in this directory and viewing index.*
   */
  |- assets/
  |- css/
  |\
  | |- styles.css
  | |- ie7.css
  |- js/
  |\
  | |- jquery.min.js
  | |- scripts.css
  |- index.php
  |- src/
  |\
  | |- App/
  | \
  |  |- Controllers/
  |  |- Models
  |  |- /* other files */
framework
  /*
   * Accessible files only via system path "/var/www/html/framework..." 
   * Not able to access via http. www.example.com/framework will not work.
   */
  |- src/
```

Comment: I'm not sure how it will work. Should index and register be in public_html too then?

Comment: How would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

can you do as you mentioned it will work fine.